# Can the LoadRunner be used for desktop applications

Tags: automation, automated-tests, loadrunner

I have used LoadRunner a long time ago for web applications, now i wonder if i can use it for desktop application automation. Is it possible ? Can someone link to any guide or examples?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner is a tool for performance testing. Usually you want to test the performance of some server that serves several clients via some form of communication. This can work for both web and desktop (and mobile) applications. 
I think what you are looking for is a functional testing tool - a tool that can use the application in an automatic way instead of the user. There is a complementary product called UFT (previously QTP) that does exactly that!

UFT - http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1172957#.UUlnERxTDRM

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner can test web and non web client-server applications for performance.   Load all of the sample applications and you will find flight samples for Web, for database, for Winsock, for DCOM, etc...   You can look to the VUGEN manuals and find all sorts of non-web based client-server protocols for use by thick client applications.